# Create Version failed. Model validation failed: Outer dimension for outputs must be unknown, outer dimension of 'Const_1:0' is 5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml

I trained an image classifier with tf.keras and exported the model after the training is done to serve it in the cloud and make online predictions.

I served my model on a localhost using :

```
tensorflow_model_server --model_base $PATH_TO_SAVEDMODEL --rest_api_port=9000 --model_name=saved_model
```

I was able to make predictions and receive results. When i tried to deploy the model in the cloud i got the error in the title.

The thing is, i want to map the classes names with the prediction results and i was able to achieve that by doing the following :

```
# after i got the label names i convert the variable to a tensor
label_names_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(label_names) # shape (5,)
```

to export the model i use this :

```
tf.saved_model.simple_save(
    sess,
    "./saved_models/v1",
    inputs={'image': model.input},
    outputs={'label' : label_names_tensor,'prediction': model.output[0]})
```

**NOTE :**

- model.output has the shape of (?,5)
- model.output[0] has the shape of (5,)

this works locally and i get the classes names mapped with the prediction results.

It is obvious where the problem is.. how can i get this to work and map the classes names correctly with the prediction result ?

I tried to use the reshape function but i couldn't get it to work. I think i need to have this in the end :

- shape of label_names_tensor --> (?,5)

so i can do this :

- --outputs = {'label' : label_names_tensor,'prediction': model.output}

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A few introductory notes. First, the reason for the requirement that the outer dimension of *inputs* be `None` is to allow for optimizations involving batching of inputs. The inputs are row-based: one row per input feature vector/matrix/tensor. Another assumption is that each input row produces exactly one output row. Since the number of input rows is variable, the number of output rows will be, too.

One consequence of this is that there is no way to output "static" information without repeating it in each of the rows. That said, if you're generally going to only be passing in one input at a time, there won't be any repetition, but you do have the extra overhead of handling the case *as if there would be more than one input/output row*. You can repeat the labeled rows as follows:

```
batch_size = tf.expand_dims(tf.shape(model.output)[0], [-1])
new_shape = tf.stack([batch_size[0], -1])
label_names_tensor = tf.reshape(tf.expand_dims(tf.tile(label_names, batch_size), [-1]), new_shape)
# ...
tf.saved_model.simple_save(
    sess,
    "./saved_models/v1",
    inputs={'image': model.input},
    outputs={'label' : label_names_tensor,'prediction': model.output})
```